# Boxlayout is not showing button on the screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

## getting the blank screen after running this code what is the problem

## after adding .kv file everything is working fine and after removing .kv file and using the only python to show the layout it is not working

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    
    class BoxLayoutExample(BoxLayout):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            b1 = Button(text="A")
            b2 = Button(text="B")
            b3 = Button(text="C")
            self.clear_widgets()
            self.add_widget(b1)
            self.add_widget(b2)
            self.add_widget(b3)
            
    
    class MainWidget(Widget):
        pass
    
    class TheLabApp(App):
        pass
    
    TheLabApp().run()
```

**This the output:)**
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zikHd.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using a `kv` file named `thelab.kv`, then your `App` has no way of knowing what you want it to look like. You will at least need to add a `build()` method to your `TheLabApp` class that returns `BoxLayoutExample()`.